# wrapfigure in a newtheorem environment: Why not put in correct place?

Tags: wrapfigure

This must be easy but I can't figure out why the "figure" is not put at the
correct spot (*in* the example) with `wrapfigure'.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]

\begin{document}
\begin{example}
  \blindtext[1]
  \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
    \framebox[0.5\textwidth]{\rule{0pt}{100pt} Figure}
  \end{wrapfigure}
  \blindtext[1]
\end{example}
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: internally theorem is implemented as a one item list and the wrapfig doc says: You must not specify a wrapfigure in any type of list environment or  or immediately before or immediately after one.

Comment: Hi David, many thanks. I tried an alternative with a minipage but that didn't come out nice. Do you have a suggestion in this case? I just have an example environment and would like to let text float around a (right-aligned, 50% textwidth) figure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally theorems are a one item list and it is a documented restriction that `wrapfig` does not work in lists.

However theorems don't usually use too much of the list structure so with care you can make it work, especially if, as here, it is not the first paragraph (where you have the extra complication of the heading which is implemented as a list item)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]

\begin{document}
\begin{example}
  \blindtext[1]

  {\makeatletter
\let\par\@@par
\par\parshape0
\everypar{}\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
    \framebox[0.5\textwidth]{\rule{0pt}{100pt} Figure}
  \end{wrapfigure}
  \blindtext[1]\par}%
\end{example}
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: *Perfect* as usual, many thanks for sharing, David. One comment (for future reference): the `\blindtext[1]` right after `\end{wrapfigure}` is crucial.