# How to insert picture here?

Tags: formatting, theorems, wrap

I want text to flow picture, as it is in the book:

[image]

And with advice of  @Johannes_B I did it with help of `minipage`, but It doesn't suit me at all things.

1. See this. First page of my document. Do you see that it is wrong?
   [image]
2. I want to insert Pictures always on the outer side of the page! but this will do it never.
3. How to add mechanism of solving this problem to my super function of adding pictures. (Before this problem it solved all my problems, in lists, environments, items, etc)
4. ## WHY WITH POWER OF LATEX NOBODY KNOWS HOW TO INSERT PICTURE IDEALLY IN ANY SUTIATION?!

**like Office 2014 - just press one button.**

I don't believe that all of latex users do a lot of manual work when try to insert a picture. But I have been trying to do it for three weeks!

I have 2 hundread pictures to insert in my book, and if I will try to insert it **manually** , I'll go crazy!

I am really shocked, that there are a lot of sutiations when nothing works.

> ```
> \documentclass{book}
> \usepackage{graphicx}
> \usepackage{mwe}
> \usepackage{amsmath}
> \usepackage{microtype}
> \usepackage{caption}
> \input{insbox.tex}
> \usepackage{threeparttable}
> \usepackage{changepage}
> \usepackage{xargs}
> \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
> \usepackage{printlen}  
> \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
>
>
> \newcounter{ct}
>
> \newlength\imageheight
>
> \newcount\narrowlinect
> \narrowlinect=0\relax 
>     \newcounter{pictnumber}  
>     \newcommand*{\wrapitem}{\apptocmd{\labelenumi}{\hskip\leftmargin}{}{}\item\apptocmd{\labelenumi}{\hskip-\leftmargin}{}{}}
>     %
>     \newcommandx{\InsertPictL}[4][1=0,3=0]{\refstepcounter{pictnumber}%
> \settoheight\imageheight{\includegraphics[width=#4\textwidth]{#2}}
> \narrowlinect=\imageheight\relax
> \setcounter{ct}{\numexpr((\narrowlinect)/\baselineskip+2)\relax}
>     \setlength{\leftskip}{\leftmargin}\mbox{}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
>     \InsertBoxL{#1}{\begin{threeparttable}%
> \begin{tabular}{c@{}}\includegraphics[width=#4\textwidth]{#2}\end{tabular}%
> \caption*{Pict. \thepictnumber}\end{threeparttable}}[\numexpr(\value{ct}/2+#1+1)]\par
> \hspace{\itemindent}
>     }%
>
>     \newcommandx{\InsertPictR}[4][1=0,3=0]{\refstepcounter{pictnumber}%
> \settoheight\imageheight{\includegraphics[width=#4\textwidth]{#2}}
> \narrowlinect=\imageheight\relax
> \setcounter{ct}{\numexpr((\narrowlinect)/\baselineskip+2)\relax}
>     \mbox{}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\setlength{\leftskip}{\leftmargin}%
>     \InsertBoxR{#1}{\hskip-\leftmargin\begin{threeparttable}%
> \begin{tabular}{c@{}}\includegraphics[width=#4\textwidth]{#2}\end{tabular}%
> \caption*{Pict. \thepictnumber}\end{threeparttable}\hskip\leftmargin}[\numexpr(\value{ct}/2+#1+1)]
>     }%
>
> \newcommandx{\InsertPict}[4][1=0,3=0]{%
> \strictpagecheck%
> \checkoddpage%
> \ifoddpage
> \InsertPictR[#1]{#2}[#3]{#4}
> \else%
> \InsertPictL[#1]{#2}[#3]{#4}
> \fi%
> }
>
>
> \begin{document}
> \noindent
> \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
> \begin{thm}
> \lipsum[1]
> \begin{equation}
> \int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 0.
> \end{equation}
> \end{thm}
> \end{minipage}%
> \hfill%
> \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
> \InsertBoxR{0}{\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr(\textwidth-2mm)]{example-image-a}}
> \end{minipage}
>
>
> \newpage
> \begin{thm}\InsertPict{example-image-a}{0.3}
> \lipsum[1]
> \begin{equation}
> \int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 0.
> \end{equation}
> \end{thm}
>
>
> \newpage
> \begin{thm}\InsertPict{example-image-a}{0.3}
> \lipsum[1]
> \begin{equation}
> \int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 0.
> \end{equation}
> \end{thm}
> \end{document}
> ```

Comment: `wrapfig` isn't suited to do the job, use `minipage`s instead.

Comment: @Johannes_B  please see my updated question.

Comment: I was mislead by your very first picture, `wrapfig` seems to be the best solution. `cutwin` is also available, but i don't have any experience. On the other hand, be advised, that wrapping images always need manual interaction.

Comment: @Johannes_B What? wrapfig works never, because it doesn't work in environments at all,
cutwin is not available for me because it doesn't work with formulas correctly.

Comment: [What can't TeX  do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27849)

Comment: I think that your question is written unnecessarily **rude**.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Where is it rude?! I am sorry.

Comment: It is just emphasizing of one important question

Comment: Maybe **too emotional** is the better description. And I is just my opinion. You can have - of course - have another.

Comment: @Dida writing like **THIS** is considered shouting in chatrooms or forums. I get you are frustrated. May I suggest to take a step back and try a different approach?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a minipage solution.  See [Wrapping image with multiple theorem-like environments and displayed math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157110/wrapping-image-with-multiple-theorem-like-environments-and-displayed-math/157370?s=3|0.0407#157370) to break a paragraph (wrap text).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
        \usepackage{graphicx}
        \usepackage{caption}
        \input{insbox.tex}
        \usepackage{threeparttable}
        \usepackage{xargs}
        \usepackage{mwe}
        \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}


\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr 0.8\textwidth-\columnsep}% need some gap
\begin{thm}[Коши]\label{abc2}
Для всякой регулярной функции $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$, заданной в односвязной области G, справедливо равенство
\begin{equation}
\label{abc3}
\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 0.
\end{equation}
где интеграл берется по любому замкнутому простому кусочно-гладкому контуру $\gamma$, лежащему в области $G$.
\end{thm}
\end{minipage}\hfill\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have already deleted my own answer, that doing it like you advice me... (because people voted down :( )
Please, see updated question.

Comment: Oh \nopar contruction from the reference should solve my first problem. But it is very manual work.

Comment: \hangindent and \parshape can automatically adjust the margins (left or right) but only affect one paragraph and don't work on equations (IIRC).