# Using figures & wrapfig in scrlttr2

Tags: floats, koma-script, wrapfigure, letters, scrlttr2

`scrlttr2` does not seem to have figures defined?

> Package caption Error: No float type 'figure' defined.

So how can I fix that?

Before you argue using figures is pointless in letters:

1. Yes, maybe, but I want it.
2. In a multi-pages letter about art it may e.g. be actually useful.
3. As far as I see I cannot wrap text around images in any other way than with `wrapfig` (wrapfigure) – does not this depend on `figure`? All guides I can find online recommend `wrapfig`. How should I wrap around an image otherwise? Even Word can do this easily and it is (also) made for creating letters.

Example code (snippet):

```
\documentclass[version=last]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code snippets. Instead, put your snippet into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Unfortunately your snippet doesn't illustrate the problem you describe.

Comment: why should wrapfig require floats? If you tried it and got an error, post your small test file and ask about the error.

Comment: What about "figures" do you want? Floating to different pages? Numbered figure captions? Or the images? Wrapfigure does not depend on figures, but the \caption command does.

Comment: Also, wrapfig is not the only way to wrap text around images, nor the best way.  Just the easiest to use.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157110/wrapping-image-with-multiple-theorem-like-environments-and-displayed-math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need floating figures and/or the `\caption` command, then use class `scrartcl` and load package `scrletter`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrletter}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Max Mustermann}
\opening{Hello \usekomavar{toname},}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{3cm}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Caption}
\end{wrapfigure}
\blindtext

\Blindtext[2]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
\caption{Another Caption}
\end{figure}
\closing{Best regards}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But is not `scrartcl` the outdated version of `scrlttr2`?

Comment: No, `scrartcl` is the article class in the KOMA-Script bundle. If you load package `scrletter` you can write a letter with this class (or `scrreprt` and `scrbook`), too.